# Optional parameter on interface based on type argument in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, optional-parameters, generic-type-argument

I would like to create a type or interface in typescript, that takes an *optional* generic parameter.  To make it optional, I use the default generic parameter syntax:

```
interface IdData {
  id: string;
}

interface WizardContext<T = undefined> {
  step: number;
  items: T extends IdData ? T[] : undefined
}
```

The concept here is that if a more specific type is built from `WizardContext`, and the type argument `T` satisfies the condition `T extends IdData`, then that specific type should have a property `items`, which is `T[]`.  Some examples of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
// ------- Defining some extended types -------------:

interface User extends IdData {
  name: string;
}

type UserWizardContext = WizardContext<User>;

// ------- Trying to satisfy those types: ------------

// Works
const userWizardProps: UserWizardContext = {
  step: 2,
  items: [{ name: 'name1', id: 'id1' }]
}
// Errors as expected, as `items` is missing
const userWizardProps2: UserWizardContext = {
  step: 2,
}

// Errors, even though items should be allowed to be undefined
const simpleWizardProps: WizardContext = {
    step: 2
}

// I have to declare items as undefined, when it should be able to just be omitted
const simpleWizardProps2: WizardContext = {
    step: 2,
    items: undefined
}
```

In the last case, even though `simpleWizardProps2` uses `WizardContext` with no type argument definition, it still errors if I don't manually include `items: undefined`.  This is essentially the difference between an optional vs undefined parameter.  I do not want `items` to be optional, because then in various other places where it is meant to be defined, I get `Object is possibly 'undefined'` issues.

I have tried doing this with types instead of interfaces as well:

```
type WizardContextType<T = undefined> = {
  step: number;
} & (T extends IdData ? { items: T[]} : {})
```

But this ultimately makes no difference.  If the type argument passed to `WizardContext` or `WizardContextType` does not extend `IdData`, `items` is still expected to be declared as `undefined`, when the goal is to actually omit it.

#### [TS playground demonstrating the issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFpM0CUHs4BdQFMAeiUDsDOBLAIwBsVREBPABxRwinvoChG8tMAnAMwEMBjUgJIATACLdE3UAG9GoUHiEAuUDkTtWAcwDcjAL7NWHHv1AB1PAC9u7IQGE4bdIgA8AFVABeUAFcsQlJysKEIAfNKyKpiUyljeALYEKOw6cniYcTjK7k7YQrTCYhKgAPygrgDaALqgyr7+gVjBeswU1GaW1nYOmBiuVChunj5+AUGhQzJyqijRoLEJSTq6oABkoAAU2Ri5+aLikqVS8umZZVXLylK6AJTMIHTQIqNYmipwcaQ5I0Jk-acMTBYji4fFIAFUcElUNs-LtCpJJnNuB9lKp1FhtM1GK1wZD2OYrDZ7I4MEMCZ1iT0XBCkiEdNj+qAAMp4OKUEjkondJxkjpckmIen3AHgMrscivRBwFTiPA4TjkMgACzgkN+1H+IsB91McHYAGscIxeA5VD48ZyhAAFdhwSinGn4vldAUTCLTWYAJgANBE0igMspykcsMiUMoAOShj4ARgj3vkSlAEYUcdAukqzXuAFF2Lb2LRuLR0NReJghAmi6AAAb+jLV+S0OJy-AY42m5DeC3Om12nCe5SOy2UnleREe5Q+rE5vN6nAJlAAN2wyrg3g0SuOAdoOBV3iIP0SoG4RCIcAA7sEyNKj3Vnk0TbhkPg2Rye7b7cph9zSWOIlMoknacwAEUAlW4Zdr1AfxeCIaxSDrQtaDvBpggTc8lRXNIVD3A9QCPbhiFIKVQAAKy7ZAj3eNJy3bJ8VFZdkUEtXt7QHdpCRdKk3TkACZknX1eK3QNhnqMY9CAA)

How can I create this optional property based on whether or not the type argument satisfies the condition?

Comment: `WizardContextType` seems to work for me... https://tsplay.dev/w25BbW and it's the same playground as yours.

Comment: Is this just a typo? You're not actually using your `WizardContextType`, or at least you're not demonstrating it.

Comment: @vr. jeeeeezzzzzz, so dumb.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in this case if T does not extends IdData the type of itens property is undefined but still required.
to create a optional property you should to use

```
interface WizardContext<T = undefined> {
  step: number;
  items?: T extends IdData ? T[] : undefined
}
```

Comment: As I said, "I do not want items to be optional, because then in various other places where it is meant to be defined, I get Object is possibly 'undefined' issues."...turns out that my `WizardContextType` does actually work as intended, my question is poorly crafted 

Comment: I'm sorry, i did not pay attention to it.